# The result of Minimize and FunctionRange are different. How can I repair?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I used

```
Minimize[{Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2], (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25}, {x, y}] // Simplify
```

> {2 Sqrt[50 - 5 Sqrt[2]], {x -> 1 - 5/Sqrt[2], y -> 2 + 5/Sqrt[2]}}

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + 
    Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2], (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25}, {x, 
   y}] // Simplify
```

> {2 Sqrt[5 (10 + Sqrt[2])], {x -> 1 + 5/Sqrt[2], y -> 2 - 5/Sqrt[2]}}

```
FunctionRange[{Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + 
    Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2], (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25}, {x, y},
   w] // Simplify
```

> 7 Sqrt[2] <= w <= 2 Sqrt[5 (10 + Sqrt[2])]

The result of `Minimize` and `FunctionRange` are different.

Comment: `Minimize` is incorrect, you can check `NMinimize` returns the same result as `FunctionRange`.  The result `Minimize` gives is actually a local maximum on the circle defined by the constraint.  I'd call this a bug.

Comment: `Minimize` in version 9 returns the correct answer. In version 10.4 and version 11.1 I get the wrong answer.

Comment: Did you file a bug report?  Get a response?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the outputs from `Minimize`

```
minM = Minimize[
   {
    Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2],
    (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
    },
   {x, y}
   ] // Simplify
(* {2 Sqrt[50 - 5 Sqrt[2]], {x -> 1 - 5/Sqrt[2], 
  y -> 2 + 5/Sqrt[2]}} *)
```

`Maximize`

```
maxM = Maximize[
   {
    Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2],
    (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
    },
   {x, y}
   ] // Simplify
(* {2 Sqrt[5 (10 + Sqrt[2])], {x -> 1 + 5/Sqrt[2], 
  y -> 2 - 5/Sqrt[2]}} *)
```

and `FunctionRange`

```
funR = FunctionRange[
   {
    Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2],
    (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
    },
   {x, y},
   z
   ] // Simplify
(* 7 Sqrt[2] <= z <= 2 Sqrt[5 (10 + Sqrt[2])] *)
```

in Mathematica version 11.1.

For the `FunctionRange` case we use `Solve` to determine the corresponding `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
{minR, maxR} = {funR[[1]], funR[[5]]}

solMinR = Solve[{
   Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2] == minR,
   (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
   },
  {x, y}
  ]
(* {{x -> -3, y -> -1}, {x -> 4, y -> 6}} *)

solMaxR = Solve[{
    Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2] == maxR,
    (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
    },
   {x, y}
   ][[1]]
(* {x -> 1/2 (2 + 5 Sqrt[2]), y -> 1/2 (4 - 5 Sqrt[2])} *)
```

We will use `ParametricPlot3D` to plot the curve in 3D space that corresponds to the function with the `x` and `y` coordinates constrained and `Graphics3D` to plot the points from `Minimize`, `Maximize` and `FunctionRange`.

It is apparent by visual inspection of the constraint

```
(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 25
```

that this is a circle of radius 5 centered at `{x,y} == {1,2}`.

This can be parameterized as

```
x = 5 Cos[θ] + 1
y = 5 Sin[θ] + 2
```

with θ ranging from zero to  2 π.

The function is re-written in terms of θ

```
Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2] + 
   Sqrt[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2] /. {x -> 5 Cos[θ] + 1, 
   y -> 5 Sin[θ] + 2} // Simplify
(* Sqrt[10] (Sqrt[5 - 3 Cos[θ] - 4 Sin[θ]] + Sqrt[
   5 + 4 Cos[θ] + 3 Sin[θ]]) *)
```

Putting this all together in the graphics below the green point is from `Minimize`, the red point from `Maximize` and the blue points from `FunctionRange`.

It is apparent that `Minimize` gives a false answer and `FunctionRange` gives the correct minimum.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {5 Cos[θ] + 1, 5 Sin[θ] + 2, 
   Sqrt[10] (Sqrt[5 - 3 Cos[θ] - 4 Sin[θ]] + Sqrt[
      5 + 4 Cos[θ] + 3 Sin[θ]])},
  {θ, 0, 2 π},
  PlotStyle -> Black
  ],
 Graphics3D[
  {
   PointSize[0.035],
   Green,
   Point[{1 - 5/Sqrt[2], 2 + 5/Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[50 - 5 Sqrt[2]]}],
   Blue,
   Point[{-3, -1, 7 Sqrt[2]}],
   Point[{4, 6, 7 Sqrt[2]}],
   Red,
   Point[{1 + 5/Sqrt[2], 2 - 5/Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[5 (10 + Sqrt[2])]}]
   }
  ],
 ViewPoint -> {0.75, -3, 1.4}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is this a bug with `Minimize`?

Comment: I believe it is. I think you should report it to Wolfram support. Worked OK in version 9.